# Can a Windows XP Pro client require two different logins by two different Users

Tags: windows-xp

I have a standalone Windows XP Pro machine NOT connected to any network.  I need to see if the native XP Pro OS has the capabilities to force 2 users to login before they can access the desktop or any applications.

Comment: Do you mean two users must login simultaneously to unlock access to the PC?

Comment: Yessir, if that is possible without the aid of a 3d party application.Perhaps a Group Policy Edit or something to the effect.  Correction....  It does not have to be simultaneous, one right after the other would be just fine.